# How to get URL of 302 redirect on Elastic Load Balancer health check?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, health-monitoring

An app is deployed on Elastic Beanstalk with an Application Load Balancer.

The health checks fail and in the dashboard under `ECS2 > Load Balancing > Target Groups` I see the response code mismatch is due to a 302 temporary redirect.

[image]

But where can I find the actual log that also shows to which URL the redirect is to further analyze the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to [enable logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html) on your ELB, and configure it to write the logs to an S3 bucket. Then you could look in that S3 bucket to see the logs.

Comment: Will the ELB checks be logged? I'm thinking OP needs to look at the web server logs on the instance.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I thought they were logged, but now I'm second guessing myself. You are correct that they would certainly be available on the web server though.

Comment: It turned out that the health check used protocol `http`, but the server app redirected to `https`. The solution was to change the health check protocol to `https`.